# How can i set an eslint rule for no-undefined?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, eslint

I am trying to make a simple function which will redirect the user to the home page, as the name say. I can't get rid of this error:

> *ReferenceError: location is not defined

Can someone help me with this, using eslint?

```
export function goToHomePage() {
  location = '/';
}
```

I am using backbone.js MVC

Comment: Try `window.location` to get around it

Comment: that leads to: ReferenceError: window is not defined. :(

Comment: Have you got `"env": { "browser": true }`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your ESLINT config to:

```
var esLintDevConfig = {
    env: {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "angular": true, "window": true, //anyother global variables
    },
    rules: {

    }
};
```